# Vue: Show/Hide image based on its own src attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to reference the current element in a vue template? I tried using `this` but that doesn't seem to work.

Basically I only want to show the `img` tag if the source attribute has a length greater than zero which changes from the selection of the bootstrap dropdown that it is within.

```html
<img id="active_item_icon" v-show="this.src.length > 0 || !!data.icon_url" :src="data.icon_url" alt="Item Icon">
```

Full Code:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="width:100%;text-align:left;" type="button" id="dropdown-item-icon-url" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <!-- This is the image that I want to watch -->
    <img id="active_item_icon" v-show="this.src.length > 0 || !!data.icon_url" :src="data.icon_url" alt="Item Icon">
    <span v-show="!data.icon_url">No Icon Selected</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%" aria-labelledby="dropdown-item-icon-url">
    <li v-on:click="updateURL" v-for="item in $store.state.icons" :key="item.id">
      <a href="#"><img :src="$store.getters.icon(item.id)" alt=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="icon_url" id="item_icon_url" :value="data.icon_url || ''">
</div>
```

Comment: did u try with: v-show="data.icon_url.length" ?

Comment: Why not use the length of the 'data.icon_url' variable? For a reference to elements, [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) could help.

Comment: The src of the image will change, it's a dropdown that when selected changes the displayed icon.

Comment: And Looking at the actual code, I do have it, I updated the question.

Comment: Why not v-if on the `data.icon_url-length` ? And remove the or in the if

Answer (score 0):

If you can access `data.icon_url` for the img tags source and it is a string, you could do a v-if on that, and remove the or.

```html
<img id="active_item_icon" v-show="data.icon_url.length > 0" :src="data.icon_url" alt="Item Icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I didn't think of this, but I just need to bind it to some data:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    showUrl: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    updateURL(e) {
      this.showUrl = e.currentTarget.querySelector('img').src
    },
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="active_item_icon" v-show="!!showUrl.length" :src="showUrl" alt="Item Icon">
```